# align button in horizontal center

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align a check box and a submit button in the center  of a simple form
I tried doing the same using "mx-auto" class.

But it is not working

How do I align my  submit Button, Check box in middle or in right side?

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>Please Login</h3>
    <form #userForm="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
                <label for="email">Email address</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-auto">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="remember-me" checked>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember-me">
                        Remember Me
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="submit" class="mx-auto">
            <button type="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">LOGIN</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the output :

[image]

Comment: try text-center

Comment: I used "text-center" for both Button and Div which has the check box. Button moved in center.
"Remember me" Label Moved in center
But The check box remained in LEFT

How to move moth LABEL and CHCK Box together to center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, you can handle it separately

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>Please Login</h3>
    <form #userForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="mx-auto">
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="remember-me" checked>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="remember-me">
                  Remember Me
              </label>
          </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
          <button type="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">LOGIN</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add the text-center class to your container, everything inside will be aligned center.
See Demo below:

```html
 <!-- CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

<div class="container text-center">   <!-- text-center here -->
      <h3>Please Login</h3>
      <form #userForm="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input
              type="email"
              class="form-control"
              id="email"
              placeholder="name@example.com"
            />
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-auto">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                value=""
                id="remember-me"
                checked
              />
              <label class="form-check-label" for="remember-me">
                Remember Me
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="submit" class="mx-auto">
          <button type="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            LOGIN
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: In the form Many times we need to align some controls to center , some to left and some to right.
The requirement is to control them separately instead of global center alignment